# 18.04.4 Unknown device in power settings

Tags: unknown-device

This device appeared in my power settings after installing ubuntu 18.04.4. I have no idea what it is. I am getting annoying 'low battery' alerts and I would like to get rid of this device from that list. I would assume that it's an Elantech device. Maybe the touchpad? Has anyone ever experience this before?

I am running the 5.0.0-25-generic kernel on an Asus Q526FA with an Intel 8th Gen i7.

[image: Power Settings]

Comment: Which device? What do `lshw`, `lsusb`, `journalctl` have to say about it?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the image. There a link to it in the original question now.

Comment: Do you have any USB devices... like a phone... plugged in?

Comment: I do charge something via usb there at night but even when i disconnect the cable it still shows 1%

Comment: `upower -d` please.

Comment: Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/keyboard_hid_0018o04F3o292Cx0002_battery
  native-path:          hid-0018:04F3:292C.0002-battery
  model:                ELAN9008:00 04F3:292C
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Sun 25 Aug 2019 06:06:42 PM EDT (52 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  keyboard
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               unknown
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          0%
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'

Comment: that is the device in question. Displayed using upower -d

Answer (score 0):

It's an [Elan](http://www.emc.com.tw/eng/) [Fingerprint reader](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1641290). You should be able to disable it with [TLP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681).

Comment: My computer doesn’t have a fingerprint reader. Is that still something that would be recognized by Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Asus probably has a very similar model which does have a fingerprint reader, and uses the same motherboard for both. That's why you see it.